# The pointless "Top Reviewers today" lists

Tags: feature-request, review, review-stats

The [Review Stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) page shows some review statistics, including lists of the top reviewers of all time and today. The last list, "Top Reviewers today" is rather pointless now that the number of review actions are limited per day and queue. All these lists are (of course) filled with people that used up all their actions for today.

I suggest that you change it into a top list of this month instead.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208267/purpose-of-top-reviewers-today-in-suggested-edit-review-stats/322187#322187

Answer (score 10):

They're only useless on sites where users actually *reach* those limits every day, like Stack Overflow. On other, smaller sites, those limits are rarely reached and the daily stats are more useful. [Even here on Meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats)

I'd much rather see them completely ditch the left chart and expand the all-time chart to include more users, or add paging functionality to browse through them more. Maybe even change it to a table that lists their all-time reviews as well as their reviews this day, week, month, and year (to be consistent with other features around the site, like the users page). Users could then click on each sorting type to actually sort the table by that number.

Comment: I'd rather they just ditch both the daily and all time charts altogether because it's a big incentive that's generating so many of the poor quality reviewers.  Making the all time board more robust would be detrimental to the system in my eyes.

Comment: I wouldn't know about those smaller sites because I seldom use them, so this post on meta.SO is specifically for SO :-) I agree that you can do a lot more to enhance the statistics page.

Comment: @Servy: The badges are a much larger incentive. I don't believe stats without badges would pose as much of a problem, but we don't really know what SE is going to do (if anything) to resolve that problem.

Comment: @animuson They added the leaderboard when the new review system first came out, and they didn't add the badges for several weeks.  The major problems were starting right away.  Now, I personally think *both* should go away as they *both* contribute.  I think removing just one without the other would help a bit, but not a lot.