# Leagues for participation/moderation?

Tags: support, moderation, reputation-leagues, participation

I am aware of reputation leagues, but those only track your rep gains.

As a person who makes everything a competition and who is active in participation/moderation (for the two and a half months I've been here at least) I am wondering if there is a leaderboard per community recording participation and moderation?

When I say participation/moderation, I mean if you took all of the users and ranked them in order considering all of the below:

- editing
- flagging
- reviewing
- voting
- meta participation
- community events
- anything else that would fit in this category

Is there such a thing?

(I know that badges do this as well, but they really don't mean much and it is not an active competition, more of a go at your own pace type thing. I believe that a league would encourage more daily/weekly moderation/participation, rather than the goal of one badge, earning it, and stopping with your moderation duties.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace accept rate with citizenship level](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165179/replace-accept-rate-with-citizenship-level)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few of these already 'sort of' exist:

The [users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users) for a site lets you sort by voters or editors, and filter by timespan too. So you can see the people that voted or edited the most on a site, for a given period of time. The [same page](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/users) for site specific meta's can also show meta participation on a site, including voting and editing.

Each [review queue has a stats page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats), where you can also see who reviewed the most.

This leaves only flagging and participation in community events as things that don't have an overview that could satisfy your curiosity.

To be honest though, the point that the [review stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180323/369802) may be an incentive to harmful behavior by gamifying the *amount* of reviews over the *quality* of those reviews has been made long ago, and I can still see a similar effect from time to time, on sites where there are no review audits.

**If you're going to make a feature request, keep this in mind:  On SE, quality is more important than quantity.** But quality is hard to capture in numbers. Even the reputation leagues don't manage to do that: Someone with a lot of lower quality posts can easily outscore people that write less, but better quality posts. Number of edits is easily artificially inflated by making minor edits instead of big ones. Voters can vote just to increase their vote count, and discard the post quality. People already do so for badges sometimes. So make sure, before making a feature request, that you're asking for leagues that will actually encourage the right behavior.

Comment: There is also [the participation tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/what-are-the-hidden-features-of-stack-exchange/226347#226347).

Comment: @Martin true. I left that out because it's only for the last 60 days, so it won't list *all of the users*, like the question asked for. But it's a nice tab!

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I just thought of one possible idea.

As Tinkeringbell brought up in her very helpful answer, there is a user page to filter users by reputation, voting, and editing (and look at moderators and new users) per week, month, quarter, year, or of all time.

Now, in your profile, if you are a relatively active user, you will have a small blue box like this:

[image]

tracking your rank in reputation leagues.

Maybe there could be a similar box for editing based on the [top editor's user page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all)?